# A complicated selecting query

Tags: mysql, select, count

```
SELECT *, IF(start_date < ".$twoDaysAgo.", (posts / 172800 * 50000), (posts / (".$curTime." - start_date) * 50000)) as rating 
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*, count(t2.id) as posts 
    FROM topics as t1 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, topic_id as tid, poster, body, post_date, poster_ip, subject 
        FROM messages t9
    ) as t2 
    ON t1.topic_id = t2.tid 
    GROUP BY t1.topic_id
) as t3 
ORDER BY rating DESC, topic_id ASC
```

posts column gives the alltime-postcounts of the topics. It is okay, I want that. But I additionally want to get the topics' postcounts in the last 2 days. In other words, I need to get the topics' alltime-postcounts and 2-day-postcounts in one query.

table topics:
[image: topics]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/802/8788454634.png))</sub>

table messages:
[image: messages]
<sub>(source: [easycaptures.com](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/802/8788454634.png))</sub>

Comment: Please add some data example and the desired result from that data. It will be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: It seems that MarcB has answered you. See if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT count(*) AS all_time, SUM(start_date > $twoDaysAgo) AS last_2_days
```

MySQL will auto-convert the start_date comparison boolean value to an integer `0` or `1`, and then sum up those 1's, effectively giving you the count you need.

Comment: Can you put it in my query?